# Continuously checking for network connectivity state

Tags: java, android, network-connection

i am building an online game so i need the phone to keep checking for the network connectivity all the time .. 
so i can notify the user that something went wrong with his Wifi or Mobile Data

Comment: use to register broadcast receivers to get notified

Comment: Why is the question tagged `android`? If it is an online game, it's independent from the platform you use to play it.

Answer (score 0):

use this to check your Internet connection and use a timer or handler and runnable to periodically check it

```
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    // it need to connect to wifi/LTE and can access the internet
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

runnable

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // check internet connection
        }finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to poll on Android, you can set up a broadcast receiver that will be called on any change on connectivity status from android 7 (API 24)

Apps will receive `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcasts if they register their `BroadcastReceiver` with `Context.registerReceiver()` as long as the context is valid.